# proof related to Hilbert Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a bounded linear compact operator on a Hilbert space $H$ over $C$, $A$ is a positive self-adjoint operator on $H$. How to show that $T=UA$ where $U^{+}U=I$ on the range $R(A)$ of $A$

Comment: Something is not phrased correctly in your question. Your condition on $U$ makes it an isometry on the range of $A$. So for any $A$ such that its range has different dimension than that of $T$, your equality is impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the question is about the [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition#Bounded_operators_on_Hilbert_space), which holds for all bounded operators on a Hilbert space (not necessarily compact). The operator $A$ is determined by $T$ as $A=(T^*T)^{1/2}$, not chosen independently.

You can find the proof of polar decomposition theorem [here](http://www.math.caltech.edu/~2010-11/3term/ma110c/operator_theory1.pdf).